# Compiling Basler Pylon SDK for OpenFrameworks on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, computer-vision, openframeworks

I am trying to use a Basler (https://www.baslerweb.com/) camera with some openCV stuff on openframeworks. I have previously used Point Grey cameras (with their "FlyCapture2" SDK) without too much trouble. Basler has something called Pylon SDK which works for Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

I can compile Pylon's own examples without any issue, but when I `#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>` then I immediately get compiler issues. I have modified the config.make file for my project appropriately (I think), so the compiler definitely finds the header files, but I keep getting errors relating to something much deeper in the Pylon library, specifically:

```
In file included from /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:30,
                 from /home/stephen/of_v0.9.8_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworks/utils/ofConstants.h:184,
                 from /home/stephen/of_v0.9.8_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworks/ofMain.h:5,
                 from /home/stephen/of_v0.9.8_linux64_release/apps/myApps/canPointerOsc/src/main.cpp:1:
/opt/pylon5/include/GenApi/Types.h:130:9: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
         None,            //!< name resides in custom namespace
```

It seems that "None" is getting defined (into a numeric constant?) somewhere else. Curiously, this never happens when compiling their own samples. Is there something about the openFrameworks compiling process (options passed to G++?) that might break this part of their own code:

```
//! Defines from which standard namespace a node name comes from
    //! \ingroup GenApi_PublicUtilities
    typedef enum _EStandardNameSpace
    {
        None,            //!< name resides in custom namespace
        GEV,             //!< name resides in GigE Vision namespace
        IIDC,            //!< name resides in 1394 IIDC namespace
        CL,              //!< name resides in camera link namespace
        USB,             //!< name resides in USB namespace
        _UndefinedStandardNameSpace  //!< Object is not yet initialized
    } EStandardNameSpace;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there were conflicting definitions via the preprocessor, possibly buried somewhere in openFrameworks itself or one of its included dependencies. Adding the following lines before including the Pylon Header file solved the issue:

```
#undef None
#undef Status
```

Goddam you, preprocessors!